# Kernel TLS Socket Redirect

Tags: networking, ssl, linux-networking, kernel, socket

Suppose both the client as well as the server are on the same machine and they want to do mTLS. They both choose to offload the TLS to Kernel (kTLS). Now when the key exchange happens, given the Kernel knows about both the sockets and the exchanged keys, is it possible to skip TLS completely and just forward HTTP data between the two sockets? Otherwise we will unnecessarily burn 2x CPU to first encrypt the data from the client and later decrypt it from the server.

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with Kernel TLS. Aren't you basically asking if you can skip TLS when communicating on localhost? Or do you mean that one could skip only the encryption and integrity part of TLS, while keeping the mutual authentication? And if this is a conceptional (rather than configuration) question than [security.se] might be more appropriate for this.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I meant the latter. In this case client doesn't even have to know that the server is on the localhost. It makes a request to server.com and IPTable redirects the traffic to the local server running on the same node. Only Kernel is aware that both the client as well as the server are on the same machine and it's managing the sockets for both.